# why c/c++ allows omission of leftmost index of a multidimensional array in a function call?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, language-design

I was just wondering why it is allowed to omit the leftmost index of a multidimensional array when passing the array to a function ? Why not more than one indexes? And how does the compiler find out the size with one index omitted ?

Comment: Could you provide some code as an example ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Other answers described how the C standard handles array to pointer conversion and how this affects the function declaration, but I feel they didn't go into the *why*, so here I go...

In C, arrays stand for tightly packed elements in memory.

```
A -> _ _ _ _ _ _ ...
i:   0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

In the above example, each of the array elements is 1 `_` wide. To find the i-th element, we thus have to go to the i-th address. (Note that the leftmost dimension (the size) doesn't matter here)

Now consider a multidimensional array:

```
B -> [_ _ _][_ _ _][_ _ _][_ _ _]...
i:    0 0 0  1 1 1  2 2 2  3 3 3
j:    0 1 2  0 1 2  0 1 2  0 1 2
     ^first row    ^third row
```

To find the offset of `A[i][j]` we need to jump over i rows (3*i) and then over j elements -> (3*i + j). Note how the size of the first dimension is also not needed here.

It should be clear by now then, that the leftmost size isn't needed when using the array, *it is only needed when you create it*.

---

Since there is no *need* to give the dimension of the leftmost index, then why not give it anyway, for completeness sake? After all, this is what is done in the Pascal programming language (a C contemporary).

Well, most functions that operate on arrays work the same for all possible array lengths, so specifying the size would only hurt your ability to reuse them.

for example, why do

```
int sum(int arr[10]){
    int s = 0, i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        s += arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

When you can do this instead:

```
int sum(int arr[], int n){
    int s = 0, i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        s += arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

---

As for omitting more then one dimension, this isn't possible when using normal multidimensional arrays (because you need to know the dimension to know when the first row ends and the second starts). However, if you are willing to spend some (little) extra memory for scratch space, it is perfectly possible to use pointers to pointers instead: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Answer (score 7):

**In a declaration**

Actually, you can't leave out the rightmost or the leftmost dimension entirely.

However, the leftmost *only* can be deduced for you if you have an initialiser.

**In a function argument list**

When you pass an array into a function by value, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element of that array. Yes, it looks from the syntax like you're passing an array but, no, you're not.

Consider:

```
void f(int ar[3])

void f(int ar[])
```

Both are confusing syntax for the equivalent:

```
void f(int* ar)
```

No trace of an array, let alone one of specifically three elements.

Now:

```
void f(int ar[][3])
```

This is confusing syntax for the equivalent:

```
void f(int (*ar)[3])
```

where `int (*)[3]` is the type of a pointer to the first element of your array (pointer to `int[3]`).

In conclusion, don't pay too much attention to the array-like syntax that looks like `[]`; it's not really representative of what's truly happening.

Comment: "declaration of ‘array’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions **except the first**" where's evidence the first can't? ... http://www.ideone.com/kR76X ...ah. I vaguely recall it being treated just like a pointer if it only has one dimension and you leave it blank.

Comment: What about `void foo(int bar[][3]);`?

Comment: @Philip: Pfft, the bit about him passing to a function is an edit to the question. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @Tomalak: Didn't notice the OP's edit. I certainly didn't intend to hint you at something, I was just curious.

Comment: @Philip: No problem; I'm glad you pointed it out. Have edited.

Comment: @Mark: You're thinking of when a function has an argument `int ar[]`; however, this is not related to declarations. :)

Comment: Since when is `void f(int ar[3])` illegal? The 3 is meaningless and useless (unless you write `static` before it) but it's not illegal as far as I know.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: the links you given in ur answer are broken.

Comment: @Destructor Dangit

Answer (score 3):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will have its type implicitly converted to "pointer to `T` and will evaluate to the address of the first element in the array.

What does any of that have to do with your question?

Assume the following lines of code:

```
int arr[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
foo(arr);
```

We pass the array expression `arr` as an argument to `foo`.  Since `arr` is not an operand of either `sizeof` or `&`, its type is implicitly converted from "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`".  Thus, we are passing a *pointer* value to `foo`, not an array.

It turns out that in a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are synonyms for `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a *pointer* to `T`, not an array of `T`.

We can write the prototype definition for `foo` as

```
void foo(int *a)     // <- foo receives a pointer to int, not an array
```

or

```
void foo(int a[])    // <-- a[] is a synonym for *a
```

Both mean the same thing; both declare `a` as a pointer to `int`.

Now let's look at multidimensional arrays.  Assume the following code:

```
int arr[10][20];
foo(arr);
```

The expression `arr` has type "10-element array of 20-element array of `int`".  By the rule described above, it will implicitly be converted to "pointer to 20-element array of `int`".  Thus, the prototype definition for `foo` can be written as

```
void foo(int (*a)[20])  // <-- foo receives a pointer to an array, not an array of arrays
```

or

```
void foo(int a[][20])  // <-- a[][20] is a synonym for (*a)[20]
```

Again, both declare `a` as a *pointer*, not an array.

This is why you can drop the leftmost (and *only* the leftmost) array index in a function parameter declaration.