# declare 2nd array without size

Tags: c++, arrays

how can declare a 2nd or multidimensional array without first size in c++?

```
class numeric 
{
    public:
    int int_array_numbers[][];
    ...
};
```

Error message:
declaration of 'int_array_numbers' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

Comment: Hope this link is helpful [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737905/why-c-c-allows-omission-of-leftmost-index-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-fun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can declare your class as template from two arguments
something like this

```
template <int N, int M>
class numeric 
{
public:
     int int_array_numbers[N][M];
...
};
```

Comment: In which case, `N` and `M` have to be compile time constants.  But it wouldn't be hard to make them arguments to the constructor, with a `std::vector<int>` member initialized to `N * M`, and an overloaded `[]` operator which did the right thing.

Answer (score 11):

You can't, C++ doesn't support VLA's (variable length arrays).

Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` instead.

Comment: @AliN you don't want to or you can't? Because if you can but you just don't want to, you should just get over it. :)

Comment: @AliN, since when vector isn't standard library? o.O

Comment: std::vector is from the standard lib, as its name implies (std == standard)