# Incomplete type element in long foo[2][]

Tags: c, struct

In the example below I don't understand why I get this error:

```
test.c:3:6: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

Here, the compiler should consider a complete type *i.e.* `[2][3]` because each sub-element has a size of 3. So, where is the problem?

```
long foo[2][] = {
    {2,3,4},
    {5,6,7}
};
```

If I complete the type using `foo[2][3]` I will get this error:

```
test.c:9:5: note: expected ‘long int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int (*)[3]’
 int bar(long* list, size_t size)
```

Using this example:

```
int bar(long* list, size_t size);

int main() {    
    bar(&foo[0], sizeof(foo[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614862/passing-a-2d-array-of-structs)

Comment: `bar(foo[0], sizeof foo[0] / sizeof foo[0][0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, the compiler should consider a complete type i.e. [2][3] because each sub-element has a size of 3. So, where is the problem?

If you had it like:

```
long foo[2][] = {
    {2,3,4},
    {5,7}
};
```

What should the compiler do in this case? Is it `[2][2]` or `[2][3]`?

In C, it's only possible to omit the *left most dimension* of an array. So, you can do:

```
long foo[][3] = {
    {2,3,4},
    {5,6,7}
};
```

Relevant post: [why c/c++ allows omission of leftmost index of a multidimensional array in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737905/why-c-c-allows-omission-of-leftmost-index-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-fun)

> note: expected ‘long int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int (*)[3]’
>    int bar(long* list, size_t size)

This is because the type you pass and `bar` expect don't match. My personal choice is to use:

```
int bar(long (*list)[3], size_t size) {

}
```

and call:

```
bar(foo, sizeof foo/sizeof foo[0]);
```

But there are other ways too. See: [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can only leave out the dimension on the leftmost side, i.e. you can do

```
long foo[][3] = { { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 ,7 } };
```

but not the other way around like you tried. It's simply not supported, perhaps because checking that the lengths of all sub-arrays are the same was deemed to costly, or whatever.

For the second problem the fact that you get an `*` in the error should lead you to remove the `&` in the call. You want the sub-array, which will decay to a pointer to the first element, not a pointer to an array.

Also, remember that `sizeof` returns the size in number of `char`s, so for an array you need to scale down:

```
bar(foo[0], sizeof foo[0] / sizeof foo[0][0]);
```

Comment: With your example I still get the error `note: expected ‘long int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int (*)[3]’`

Answer (score 0):

Yes below code will not compile as:

```
long foo[2][] = {
    {2,3,4},
    {5,6,7}
};
```

declaration of 'foo' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
 long foo[2][] = {

you can successfully compile the below code:

```
long foo[][3] = {
    {2,3,4},
    {5,6,7}
};
```

I am able to successfully compile the below code:

```
long foo[2][3] = {
        {2,3,4},
        {5,6,7}
    }; 


  ^
```

Comment: You didn't cover the second error: `test.c:9:5: note: expected ‘long int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int (*)[3]’`